# Making a tidy (perl) return

Tags: perl, return, subroutine

It is most probably a stupid question, but here goes:

In many modules I have multiple points at which I return to the calling script. But before actually returning, I need to do some tidy-up chores, such as changing directory to the parent dir, etc.

I wrote a sub that does that for all return points. However, the only way I could think of to use it was to have

```
tidy_up();
return (LIST);
```

I would like to have a sub that accepts the returning value(s) LIST and have that sub also return to the calling script:

```
tidy_up_and_return(LIST);
```

Is that at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably isn't a good idea. There's a bunch of subtle gotchas waiting to happen around caller context.

However - `return` isn't actually required by a sub - if there is no `return` the sub implicitly returns the result of the last calculation.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub parent { 
   my @results = ( "one", "two" ); 
   child ( @results, "some_other_value" ); 
}

sub child {
   return ( @_ ); 
}

print parent();
```

Because `child` returns it's parameters - as the last line of `parent` is to call `child` - then `parent` implicitly returns the result of `child`.

I would suggest that you not do this though, as I'd call it bad style - a future maintenance programmer won't necessarily know that's what you're doing.

You can maybe improve that slightly by:

```
return child ( @results, "some_other_value" );
```

But bear in mind that you can end up with some slight oddness with return context - e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub parent {
    my @results = ( "one", "two" );
    return child( @results, "some_other_value" );
}

sub child {
    return (@_);
}

my $result =  parent();
print $result;
```

vs.

```
sub parent2 {
    my @results = ( "one", "two" );
    return ( @results, "some_other_value" );
}

my $result =  parent2();
print $result;
```

Looks pretty similar, but doesn't have the same result, because of the context of the operations.

Comment: OK, convincing, but I have multiple return points, some are error return, others return different lists. In all but the last in scope, an _explicit_ return is a must, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is. Implicit return only works at the end of your sub. I don't like implicit returns generally - they're a good way for end up with problems in future, as someone adds a 'print' right a the end, to diagnose something, for example.

Comment: Thanks! Well, one more line is not too painful, right?

Comment: Thanks! I also don't like "defaults". In addition to your example, it is obscure and bad for newbies, and it might be changed. The only exception I allow myself is when extracting input arguments in a sub with a 'shift;' It is easier to maintain. Even there, when the list gets longer than 3 or 4 I revert to passing a (reference to a) hash. Well, one more line is not too painful, right?

Comment: The only thing that really matters when writing your code is how readable it is. Lay it out for maximal neatness, elegance and clarity and let the rest take care of itself. It almost always works fine, and on the odd occasions where you need a little more speed, then you should be using a profiler to find out where to focus optimisations.